# How to access the PC pointer (using assembly) in AVR-libc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, branch, avr

I am trying to write some conditional jumps in AVR assembly using AVR-gcc. According to AVR instruction set manual, the `brxx` instructions take in an operand `k`, and jumps to `PC+k+1`. Also, according to the tutorial PDF from http://www.avrbeginners.net/new/tutorials/jumps-calls-and-the-stack/, I should be able to use the `PC` operand to jump like this:

```
brne PC+2
```

However, when I write such test code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
.section .text
.global main ; Note [5]
main:
    sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRA), PA0
    sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA), PA0
    ldi 16, 0xFF
    cpi 16, 0xFF
    breq PC + 2
    cbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA), PA0
    rjmp end

end:
    rjmp end
```

I get this error:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu="atmega16" -DF_CPU="16000000UL" -O0 main.S -o main.o
/tmp/ccAa2ySf.o: In function `main':
(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `PC'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Apparently PC is not defined in AVR-libc. Then how am I going to do such condition branch? Thanks!

**Update 1**

I found this question [How can I jump relative to the PC using the gnu assembler for AVR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761197/how-can-i-jump-relative-to-the-pc-using-the-gnu-assembler-for-avr) and found that the syntax for gnu as is `breq .+2`. However, I get the same error as that question have. When I disassemble using `avr-objdump -d main.o`, I do get

```
  74:   01 f0           breq    .+0             ;  0x76
```

Which is the same symptom as that question. I will try using linker script, but I have no experience in that.

**Update 2**

Actually I found that if I use even numbers in the breq instruction, like `breq .+2` or `breq .+4`, the objdump shows correct result. However, if I use odd numbers, it will become `breq .+0`. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Jump to labels.  Why would you ever jump using a magic number?  That defeats a big part of the reason for using an assembler in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is totally rewritten now. This is what I understand from the `objdump` of compiled C codes. Firstly, `binutils` uses byte addressing, not word addressing, for the program counter, and starts at the instruction right after the current one. This is explained in the following code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
.section .text
.global main
main:
    sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRA), PA0
    sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA), PA0
    ldi 16, 0xFF
    cpi 16, 0xFF
    breq .+4  ;; If we are executing here
    cbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA), PA0  ;; This is .+0, will be skipped
    cbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA), PA0  ;; This is .+2, will be skipped
    cbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA), PA0  ;; This is .+4, which will be executed
    rjmp end

end:
    rjmp end
```

Apparently, the PC width has nothing to do with relative address. It only affects the maximum PC value, either 0xFF or 0xFFF, so no matter what AVR platform I am compiling for, `binutils` uses two bytes for an instruction.

P.S. I think, if the only way I can know how a compiler works is to observe how it works, probably that means poor documentation? Or maybe I just don't know when to start. If someone see this, could you help pointing some useful books about 'this kind of things'? (I don't even know how to describe it) Thanks!

Comment: binutils uses 2 bytes because all instructions generate "16-bits opcodes". It is not binutils it is the AVR Instruction Set specification.

Answer (score 0):

An 8-bit MCU does not mean the assembly instructions are encoded as an 8-bit opcode. From the ATmega16 specification. 
Most AVR instructions have a single 16-bit word format. 
 On the contratry even if the ATmega are 8-bits MCUs the instructions used are encoded as 16-bits opcodes. Look at the "AVR Instruction Set". This is the reason the program counter (PC) behaves as such (only assignments to 16-bit/2-byte aligned addresses). If it were able to be set to an 8-bit/1-byte aligned address it will try to execute an invalid opcode! 
Here's a thing for you to do. Compile your example above to an object file. Then disassemble the file (use objdump -D) and look at the generated disassembly. The offsets of the instructions should be 16-bit aligned.

Comment: Yes, I found that out.

Answer (score 0):

> Then how am I going to do such condition branch?

Just define a label and branch to it.  The assembler will calculate the offset for you!

```lisp
    brne some_label2
    ; code1
some_label2:
    ; code2
```

In the case when the branch target is out of reach, do a jumpity-jump on the reversed condition:

```lisp
    breq some_label1
    [r]jmp some_labe2
some_label1:
    ; code1
some_label2:
    ; code2
```

The GNU assembler also supports a special kind of labels, which is just some number, and you can use the same label more than once.  The jump target is the first to be found in `f`orward direction resp. `b`ackward direction:

```lisp
1:
    ; code 1
    brne 1b ; jump to label 1 above (backwards)
    brcc 1f ; jump to label 1 below (forwards)
    ; code 2
1:
```

This might be useful when you are writing [assembly macros](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.39/as/Macro.html) that contain local labels.

Specifically to be used in assembly macros, there is also pseudo variable `\@` which is increased with every macro use, and thus can also be used to declare labels without conflicts:

```
.macro loop reg
    .Lloop\@:
        dec \reg
        brne .Lloop\@
.endm

    loop r16
    loop r16
```

---

### How to access the PC Pointer

If you really need the value of the program counter for some obscure reason, you can

```cpp
    rcall .
#ifdef __AVR_3_BYTE_PC__
    pop  r18
#endif 
    pop  r17
    pop  r16
```

and you have the word-address of the code location right after the `rcall`.  Symbol `.` is the assembler's *"current location"*.

Depending on the situation, it might be easier to just define a label and take the address of it:

```lisp
main:
    ldi r16,lo8(main)     ; Byte-address, low byte
    ldi r17,hi8(main)     ; Byte-address, high byte
    ldi r18,hh8(main)     ; Byte-address, highest byte

    ldi r19,pm_lo8(main)  ; Word-address, low byte
    ldi r20,pm_hi8(main)  ; Word-address, high byte
    ldi r21,pm_hh8(main)  ; Word-address, highest byte

    ldi r22,lo8(gs(main)) ; Word-address where the linker will 
    ldi r23,hi8(gs(main)) ; generate a stub as needed.
```